# how to fix the SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

this is my first laravel project and i can't fix this , this is my code's , i checked my database name , it's matched!

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:65DGZwggxTjH81a3wU4y+2vUJMja5bmnGIqi3ytYQfQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=D:\PHP\DGAPI\database01.sql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

this is my error
[Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adCzn.png)

Comment: DB_DATABASE should be equal to the name of the database, not to the path of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=        //your databse name not write path
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

i think your databse name is database01

**so please put  `DB_DATABASE=database01` in your `env` file**

Comment: please give upvote this answer THANK YOU @Milid Mokhtari